# Legendre expansion of functions

Tags: symbolic, special-functions

I am given the expansion for the Legendre function of the first kind. It is just

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}P_{n}(x).$$

I have found the expression for the coefficient $A_{n}$.
However I would like *Mathematica* to perform this task for me symbolically. How should I go about doing this? Could someone steer me in the right direction?

The mathematical operation involved here is "inner product" properties and "norm" properties. The idea is orthogonality of functions.
More information will be provided-my workings can be provided if requested.

Comment: You can use `Integrate` to perform the inner product, can you not?

Comment: Have you looked at the LegendreP` function?

Comment: It's in the docs for `LegendreP`, under "Applications" >  "Generalized Fourier transform for functions on the interval -1 to 1"